# como usar a função LPAD com à COUNT?

Tags: mysql

Apenas para exemplificação:

Estou tentando fazer um select em que sera adicionado um zero à esquerda caso o número for menor que 10.

**Exemplos:**

```
SELECT COUNT(1);
```

**Retorna => 1**

```
SELECT LPAD(1, 2, 0);
```

**Retorna => 01**

```
SELECT LPAD(COUNT(1), 2, 0);
```

**Retorna => BLOB**

Como faço para usar a função **LPAD** com à **COUNT**, ou alguma que faça algo similar?

Comment: Testei seu código no meu servidor e funcionou, qual a versão do seu `MySQL`?

Comment: Estranho, para mim sempre retorna "blob". A versão do mysql aqui é: 5.6.39-cll-lve

Comment: Testei em outro servidor e retornou corretamente também, só para informação a versão desse servidor é `5.6.39-83.1`.

Answer (score 0):

Depois de pesquisar um pouco, descobrir que isso pode ser um bug gerado pelo Drive. Assim, o problema que estava ocorrendo comigo, não necessariamente acontecerá em outros computadores.

Para corrigir isso, e ter o valor esperado em meu select, basta que eu faça um casting deste blob.

```
SELECT CAST(LPAD(COUNT(1), 2, 0) AS CHAR(2));
```

**Retorna => 01**